# EASY! Labview Race Condition

Tags: loops, race-condition, labview

I'm very new to LabVIEW... I need to write a simple program in LabView to update the value of an encoder.

Long story short... In a loop, I need to manipulate variables in this order:

1. New Value = Old Value + Current Value
2. Old Value = New Value

How do I prevent accidentally storing the old value before I calculate the new value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you monitoring whether the value changes? Add one more variable `New Value2`, assign `New Value2 = New Value` before doing `1.New Value = Old Value + Current Value`, then compare `if (New Value != New Value2)`, then do step 2. But I am wondering how could that happen if it is skipping step 1 and jump to step 2 if you are not talking about value changes

Comment: *face palm* This will probably fix it thank you. It's not skipping step 1, they just both happen at the "same" time, so sometimes its equivalently computing new value = new value + current value.

Comment: np, give it a try :)

Comment: Correctly programmed that should not be possible. Can you show your labview code?

Comment: that "EASY!" caught me off guard, I'm lmao right now hahahah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to pass the old value via a shift register (or feed back node, is the same). Here is the code snippet that shows you how to do it:

[image]

You can check that it works by looking at the New and Old values array.

A side note since your new, you can import code snippets directly into labview.